# Get-ChildItem -Recurse não retorna recursivamente

Tags: powershell

Estou tentando criar um script em powershell para manipular os arquivos de um diretório, porém ao utilizar o parâmetro `-Recurse` não tenho obtido os itens das subpastas

```
    # onde $source = C:\Files
    # e dentro de Files tem mais duas pastas 001 e 002 com arquivos dentros
    Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Filter * |
    ForEach-Object {

        #Recupera a data atual da movimentação
        $date = (Get-Date).ToString();

        #Adiciona conteúdo ao arquivo $log com a data atual da movimentação
        Add-Content -Path $log " $date - O arquivo $_ foi transferido de $source para $target";

        #Escreve em tela
        Write-Host " $date - O arquivo $_ foi transferido de $source para $target";

        #Realiza a copia dos itens
        Move-Item $_.FullName $target;
    }
```

quanto testo o comando `Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse ...` no cmdlet do powershell ele roda normal, mas dentro do script ps1 não

Comment: Tente executar o ise como administrador ... não certeza se vai resolver. Ta falando perguntas de powershell aqui :P

Comment: eu estou como administrador já e o script está com direitos também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Filter * | 
Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object {

        # Get the current date
        $date = (Get-Date).ToString();

        # Add to log file
        Add-Content -Path $log " $date - The file $_ was moved from $source to $target";

        # Show on cmdlet
        Write-Host " $date - O arquivo $_ foi transferido de $source para $target";

        # Move items
        Move-Item $_.FullName $target;
    }
```

A propriedade .PSIsContainer retorna `true` quando o item é um container (um diretório).

No PowerShell v3 e superior pode ser usado da seguinte maneira:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Directory -Recurse -Filter *
```

[Link para resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422112/get-childitem-recurse-dont-work-recursive?noredirect=1#33422414)